# What is the best way to handle the generic list and collection for jaxB serialization

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm aware that for handling generic list/collection I have more than single option.

I used XML annotation **(@XmlElement(type = 'specify the type here can be user defined or primary type')** to achieve this, but I like to know is it a good approach and do this has any drawback in further.

I preferred annotation because, the code is already established and I'm not sure how it affects other parts of the code if I change the generic types into a specific type.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you talk about "generic" types, you're not talking about Java *generics*, e.g. the `E` in `List<E>`, but are talking about base classes and/or interfaces? Because you're using the word "generic" right next to "list" and "collection", and both [`List<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`Collection<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) are [*generic types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) in Java.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, sorry for using word generic here I should have said that my code has an untyped  list and collection ie., ex: private ArrayList responseList; where responseList hold the userdefined object of type 'ResponseCR' (ie., a class),

Comment: If you have a *raw* `List`, then you are already far down the wrong path. Don't use [*raw types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: As I mentioned in question this is the code from old established private software, so I'm afraid what effects it does if I change this raw lists into typed lists and I'm not sure if the other guys willing to spend reasonable time on this. so, I came up with the XML annotations that leaves the code as it is and used annotation it recognize the type while marshal and unmarshal, but I just want to know does it lead to any other problem further down in the path. or is there any better solution for this problem.

Comment: You question didn't say old, just "already established". Generics were introduced in Java 5 back in 2004, and that is not old, but ancient.

Comment: yea I know, this software is way back guess you can call it as ancient. so do you have any suggestions on this.